# Copying entire file system (linux)

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have a need to copy an entire file system (several TB) from one disk (Raid array) to another. It would be nice to keep the file system online during the transfer as the file system is used (lightly) constantly. However, an outage is acceptable if needed.

The two methods that seem obvious to me are using `cp` or `dd`. Using cp seems more likely to produce a reliable copy, but also seems like it would be slower. Using dd ought to be faster, but I'd be worried about having a corrupted file system when I'm done. In either case, the plan would be to use rsync to handle copying any differences after the copy.

Is there a better on-line solution that I'm missing?

Comment: Can you use the sync options in your RAID array?

Comment: Unlikely. One raid uses mdadm inside linux. The other is handled by vmware and is transparent to the OS. That's part of the reason for the migration.

Comment: I would probably grasp the nettle and make an off-line copy with `dd`, but it will take some time: I measure 25MB/s, or ~11hr/TB. Although `cp` is a slower process, it won't copy empty space, so it may not be slower overall, but it won't be a completely faithful copy (eg a file with multiple hard-linked directory entries will produce multiple copies).

Comment: @AFH Thanks for that note about hard-links. That answers the question for me as there are more hard-links than I can shake a stick at. If I made multiple copies of those files, I would not have even close to enough room.

Would you care to make that an answer? I realize telling me to do it off-line isn't a direct answer to the question of a better online solution, but it does give me my overall answer.

Comment: If you want to keep hard-links, you could create a "backup" using tar (exclude /dev and similar directories) and extract it, leaving links intact.

Comment: Sorry, I was over hasty in my assertions. I have just done some tests to confirm, and it appears that `cp` _does_ maintain hard links, after all. I've no idea how it does it, but I guess if `tar` can do it, so can `cp`. That said, I'd still favour the slow and sure approach of using `dd` off-line: it guarantees an identical copy, regardless of the file structure or contents. I prefer to do this through the copy/paste functions in `gparted`: the GUI lessens the chance of making a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There's always the classic cpio:

```
# cd /source
# find .|cpio -pdvulm /dest
```

Preserves links, even copies device nodes if existing.